# Adobe flash for BBC Radio iplayer

Tags: internet-radio

I'm new to Ubuntu. I'd like to listen to BBC radio. Listen again/sounds and can't. BBC says to download Adobe flash player.

How do I do this on Ubuntu?

Comment: If you talking about `https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/live:bbc_1xtra` for example, it ***does*** play under Firefox without any problem. There should be no need Adobe Flash Player.

Comment: I listen to it all the time on Chromium / Brave browsers - no flashplayer here either

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need to add the required repository (collection of software)
`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"`.

Next, you will need to install any updates via `sudo apt update`.

Then, run this command to install Flash Player: `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer`. Run all of this in the terminal, and remember that you will have to restart your browser.

You might want to verify the installation on the [Adobe website](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) (optional).

More info [here](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-adobe-flash-player-on-ubuntu/).